# meaning of "pullback along" in the definition of pullback in category theory

Tags: category-theory, definition

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes $\textit{elementary categories, elementary toposes}$ by McLarty

> $\quad$$\textbf{Definition 1: }$  Given $f_1:A_1\rightarrow A$ and $f_2:A_2\rightarrow A$, we say that the  commutative diagram

[image]

> is a $\textbf{pullback}$ (also $(g_1, g_2)$ is a $\textbf{pullback}$ of $(f_1,f_2),$ $g_1$ is a $\textbf{pullback of }$ $f_1$ $\textbf{along}$ $f_2$, etc), if it has the property that any commutative diagram $f_2\circ g'_1=f_1\circ g'_2$

[image: [Image]]

> can be completed by a unique $\psi$ as show above.
> The dual construction is called a $\textbf{pushout}.$
> [Image]

> $\quad$$\textbf{Definition 2: }$ For any arrow $f:A\rightarrow B$ the projection arrows in a pullback of $f$ along itself are called a $\textit{kernel pair}$ for $f$

[image]

$\textbf{Questions:}$

What I would like to know is that what does it mean in the definition of a pullback, the phrase "$g_1$ $\text{ is a }$ $\textbf{pullback of }$ $f_1$ $\textbf{along}$ $f_2.$  Similarly in the definition for kernel pair, in terms of pullback square commutative diagram, what does it means to say that a projection function $f$ in a "pullback along itself".  I am not sure if I am suppose to visualize some sort of motion along the direction of the arrows in these commutative diagrams.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Definition 1 says what it means. Is there something about Definition 1 that you don't get?

Comment: @LeeMosher I just don't understand the phrase "pullback along", when i move to the case for pair of functions or pullback along itself, it becomes more confusing.  Like is the phrase "pullback along" suppose to conjure some kind of motion along or opposite the direction of arrows.

Comment: I guess you are supposed to visualize the vertical arrow $f_1$ moving "along" the horizontal arrow $f_2$ (backwards, because it's a pullback) to produce the arrows $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Comment: @Ted do I do the same for the case of pullback along itself. for kernel pair? Also in the commutative diagram for definition 2, should there be two $f$s and also another $u$ on their respective opposite sides?

Comment: It may be that you have to take the intuition described by @Ted for that special case, and then be satisfied with the extension of the terminology beyond that special case, *even though* the intuition itself does not extend. This happens only all the time with mathematical terminology.

Comment: The "pullback of $f$ along itself" for the kernel pair looks like a typo to me. The kernel pair is a pullback of (the unique arrow) $0 \to B$ along $f$.

Comment: @Ted when you say that I visualize the vertical arrow $f_1$ along the horizontal arrow $f_2$ to $g_2$, is that what it means when it says "$g_1$ is a $\textbf{pullback of }$ $f_1$ $\textbf{along}$ $f_2$"?  What about the phrase "$(g_1, g_2)$ is a $\textbf{pullback}$ of $(f_1,f_2),$?"  What gets pullback along when you are talking about pair of arrows appearing in opposite sides of a diagram.  By the way, the notion of pullback only applies to commutative square diagrams?

Comment: @Ted for the kernel pair, i should visualize the $0$ to $B$ arrow, and move it along arrow $f$ to get to arrow $u$, is that what you mean?  Sorry for my late replied, I just saw your comment just now.

Comment: In the definition of pullback $P(f_1,f_2)$, the two maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ enter in a symmetric way. However, one can also view $P(-,f_2)$ as an operation that is applied to $f_1$, so $P(f_1,f_2)$ is the result of applying $P(-,f_2)$ to $f_1$. It is similar to "the product of a and b" vs "multiplying a with b".

Comment: @MarcOlschok when it is stated that $g_1$ is a pullback along $f_1$ along $f_2$, what role do $g_2$ plays?   Also, can I can say that $g_2$ is a pullback along $f_2$ along $f_1$?

Comment: Yes one could equally say "$g_2$ is a pullback of $f_2$ along $f_1$.  It is a matter of perspective: for instance, suppose that $f_1$ is the inclusion of a subobject $A_1$ of $A$. Then "pulling back along $f_2$" would produce a subobject of $A_2$. In this situation one would perhaps not even bother to give $g_2$ a name, because it would be seen as the restriction of $f_2$.

Comment: @MarcOlschok is that the reason why pullback diagram always involve pairs of functions and the shape of the diagram is always a square?  I mean, it can't be something like a triangle.

Comment: Yes. When you proceed in the books you are using, you will find the general notion of a limit for a diagram (or for a functor). The shape of the diagram (which is $\bullet\rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet$ in the case of a pullback) determines the shape of the limit cone.

Comment: @MarcOlschok ah ok ok.  Thanks you for all of your clarifications.

Comment: @Ted You gave the definition of "kernel of $f$" in a category with pullbacks and a zero object. In a general category with pullbacks, the "kernel pair $f$" is indeed defined as the pullback of $f$ along itself. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair).