# Quick further question about the notion of "pullback/pushout".

Tags: category-theory, pullback

Previously, I asked a question about the notion of "pullback" in category theory [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636191/meaning-off-pullback-along-in-the-definition-of-pullback-in-category-theory?noredirect=1#comment9788897_4636191), I just have one further quick question about the concept of "pullback/pushout", that is, does the concept always make reference to square shape commutative diagrams, or can it be some other commutative diagram shapes.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pullback generally refers to the square-shaped diagrams.

But! Pullbacks are limits of diagrams that look like this: $$\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longleftarrow\bullet$$

Limits of diagrams that look like this: $$\bullet\\\downarrow\\\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longleftarrow\bullet$$

Could reasonably also be called pullbacks. More generally, limits of diagrams of the form: one object $X$, some set $I$, for each $i\in I$ an object $A_i$ and a single arrow $f_i:A_i\to X$, could be called pullbacks. However, such a limit could be encoded as a limit of a square diagram of form: $$X\overset{\Delta}{\longrightarrow}\prod_{i\in I}X\overset{\prod_if_i}{\longleftarrow}\prod_{i\in I}A_i$$

Which is a pullback of the usual type, so there is no real difference. It may be a good exercise to check this for yourself.

Pullbacks of the more general form are relevant e.g. in the discussion and use of "*intersections*" of subobjects. This dualises to *unions*, which are (generalised) pushouts of the dual diagrams to those above, for instance colimits of something like this: $$\bullet\\\uparrow\\\bullet\longleftarrow\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet$$(Where each arrow is monic, in the specific context of "unions").

Comment: so when I have a pullback of a diagram like:  $\cdot\rightarrow\cdot\leftarrow\cdot$, i can always construct a commutative square for it to get the pullback commutative diagram.  Also, pullback diagrams always refer to between two pairs of functions?

Comment: @Seth I'm sorry but the comment is unclear, especially in the last sentence. In the first sentence, yes, the pullback commutative square you've seen is by (equivalent) definition the limit of a diagram $\bullet\to\bullet\leftarrow\bullet$

Comment: in the other post, it states in the quoted text "$(g_1, g_2)$ is a $\textbf{pullback}$ of $(f_1,f_2),$"  Hence I am wondering if pullback always refer to pairs of functions.

Comment: @Seth I've already answered the question about "what does pullback refer to". Here, $f_1$ and $f_2$ will just be the two arrows in $\bullet\to\bullet\leftarrow\bullet$

Comment: in my original post, I was confused why it has $f_1$ is a pullback along...., and then it has $(g_1, g_2)$ is a $\textbf{pullback}$ of $(f_1,f_2),$$(g_1, g_2)$ is a $\textbf{pullback}$ of $(f_1,f_2),$.  Hence my confusion.  I think Arbib and Manes did not really explain what he meant by when he says $(g_1, g_2)$ is a pullback of $(f_1, f_2)$ in the sense does it always refer to between pairs of functions.  Like he doesn't really define everything in the text and just bold face certain concepts and expect their readers to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Seth This is now quite a different question. But, ok. If we take the pullback of $A\overset{f_1}{\rightarrow}B\overset{f_2}{\leftarrow}C$ then that entails two new arrows $g_2:X\to A$, $g_1:X\to C$, and we could call $g_2$ the pullback of $f_2$ along $f_1$, and $g_1$ the pullback of $f_1$ along $f_2$.

Comment: ah....that is how one gets the square commutative diagram.  Because I always wonder when you have one function is a pullback along another, say $f_1$ is a pullback along $g_1$ along $f_2$, I always wonder why we need $g_2$.  I am guessing that is why.

Comment: @Seth $g_2$ is implicit in "pullback". It is "needed" by definition of limit

Comment: ah kk. I will take your word for it.  Even though the notion of "limit/colimit" is still a bit of hazy to me conceptually at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have wide pullbacks or pushouts.

Wide pullbacks have more than two 'legs'. See the NLab article to see it described more fully. The wide pushout is its dual.

You also have homotopy pullbacks and pushouts. These make sense in homotopical situations where the ordinary pullback or pushout doesn't make sense. There is an extensive theory about this.

Comment: ah kk, thank you for the reference.  I did not know there is such a thing as a wide pullback.